How to customize table class names on efcore when scaffolding
I have a database with a Task table, that is conflicting with System.Threading.Tasks.Task.
My idea is to add a Db prefix to all tables. Is this doable? is there another way to prevent this conflict?

This isn't a scaffolding problem. You'd get the same problem if you used raw ADO.NET but still named your class Task. The easiest solution would be to not use just Task but something more descriptive, eg JobTask, or ProcessTask, JobStep. At the language level you can solve this by namespace or type aliasing, or explicitly using the namespace whenever there's a conflict. There's always the chance you'll forget this and get compilation or runtime errors though.

Use EF Core Power Tools

@ErikEJ nice! can I do it programmatically on the cli? for all tables?

Yes, read the docs in the wiki
